# Using java Map in scala

Tags: scala

I am thoroughly confused by this behavior in the Scala REPL:

```
scala> import java.util.Map
import java.util.Map

scala> import java.util.HashMap
import java.util.HashMap

scala> val jMap:java.util.Map[String,Int]=new HashMap[String,Int]("first"->1,"second" -> 2)

<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : (String, Int)
required: Float
   val jMap =new HashMap[String,Int]("first"->1,"second" -> 2)
                                                                     ^
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
found   : (String, Int)
required: Float
   val jMap=new HashMap[String,Int]("first"->1,"second" -> 2)
                                                                                  ^
```

Can someone help explain what's going on here ?

Comment: Simply because the expression ` x -> y` create a tuple `(x,y)`. [Hashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) constructor cannot take a Tuple2 as an argument.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`java.util.HashMap` does not provide capability to construct the map by passing a vararg of `(K, V)`, but there is a two-arg constructor accepting `initialCapacity: Int` and `loadFactor: Float`, that's why you're getting the compile error about a Float being required.

*(updated for scala 2.13+)* The idiomatic approach in Scala would be to just use Scala immutable maps (no imports required):

```
val map = Map("first" -> 1, "second" -> 2).asJava
```

If your Scala code works with a Java library that returns a `java.util.Map`, you can convert it into a Scala map explicitly by using `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters` like so:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

val javaMap: java.util.Map[String, String] = // ...
val map = javaMap.asScala

// or vice versa if you need to pass it into the Java API

val javaMap = Map("first" -> 1, "second" -> 2).asJava
```

Note that `asScala` is just a wrapper to the underlying Java map (so if that one is mutable, the wrapped map will also be mutable) and is an instance of `scala.collection.Map`. In order to be fully idiomatic and benefit from Scala's immutability guarantees, you might need to add another `.toMap` at the end that will convert it to `scala.collection.immutable.Map` (which is the default Map).

If you use scala 2.12 or older, instead of `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` import `scala.collection.JavaConverters._`.

Comment: Ok, this explains it. Thanks.

Comment: I think `JavaConversions` is going to be deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper-M, I checked up [fresh JavaConversions in scala source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/cdc011f9aefc030057575ec075f3c657c92f23de/src/library/scala/collection/JavaConversions.scala), confirmed and updated my answer accordingly.